# Django: pull pk from form submitted data into subsequent URL

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

So I have one page which contains a form so that the user can submit data to the database and a second page which contains specific fields from that record by using the assigned pk value.

My question is whether I can use the submit button to post the data to the database **and then immediately load up a URL** with the pk value from that submitted record to use some of the fields? Or would this need to be done in 2 steps? i.e. 1. insert data into DB, then 2. load the URL with the relevant pk..

**`urls.py`**:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .views import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', UserView.as_view(), name='user_new.html'),
    # form temporarily directs here after saving the data to the DB
    url(r'^thanks/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='thanks.html'), name='thanks'),
    # I would like it to go here instead
    path('adherence_agreement/<int:id>', views.adherence_agreement, name='adherence_agreement'),
]
```

**`views.py`**:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView,CreateView

class UserView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'user_new.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = 'thanks/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            form = UserForm()

def adherence_agreement(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(UserInfo, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'adherence_agreement.html', {'item': item})
```

At the moment, after you have clicked the "submit" button, the info is saved to the DB correctly and a basic page that says "Thanks!" is displayed (`thanks.html`). Also, if I enter the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/userregistration/adherence_agreement/6` it takes me to a page that has certain fields pulled from that record (I manually enter the 6 in the URL based on a record in the DB).

**`adherence_agreement.html`**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container" id="printable">
    <br>
    <img src="{% static 'RDConnect_300dpi_RGB.jpg' %}" alt="" style="
                                                                                display: block;
                                                                                margin-left: auto;
                                                                                margin-right: auto;
                                                                                width: 60%;
                                                                            "/>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <h3>Adherence agreement for authorized access to data and biospecimens in the RD-Connect Genome-Phenome Analysis Platform (RDC-GPAP)<sup><a href="#fn1" id="ref1">1</a></sup><small class="text-muted"> to be used together with the <span class="text-info">Code of Conduct</span> for integrated user access to RDC-GPAP for health-related information and human biological samples.</small></h3>
    <hr>
    <h4>Effective as of 9<sup>th</sup> November 2015</h4>
    <p>Communication to Mats G. Hansson, Centre for Research Ethics & Bioethics at Uppsala University: mats.hansson@crb.uu.se</p>
    <hr>

    <p>I, <span class="text-success">{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</span>, acting on behalf of the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span>, and holding the position <span class="text-success">{{ item.job_title }}</span>, herewith declare:</p>
    <ol type="1">
        <li>I have the authority to represent and engage the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> for the purpose of the project, <span class="text-success">[project name]</span>. For this project we ask for access to data and/or biospecimens in accordance with our research interests as set out in our completed <span class="text-info">User Verification Form</span> (previous page).</li>
        <br>
        <li>The <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> agrees to fully endorse and adhere to the <span class="text-info">Code of Conduct</span> for integrated user access to the RDC-GPAP for health-related information and human biological samples, version 2, 3rd November 2017. It shall apply to all data and biospecimen processing activities carried out within the project <span class="text-success">[project name]</span>. The personal data protection framework is thus in part formalized through this Code.</li>
        <br>
        <li>The <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> will ensure the implementation of all measures required by the provisions of this Code.</li>
        <br>
        <li>The <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> will ensure compliance with this Code by all staff and personnel working within the project on behalf of the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span>.</li>
        <br>
        <li>In addition to the rules laid out by the Code, the following project specific rules shall apply:</li>
        <br>
        <ol type="a">
            <li>There will be no attempt to try to identify or contact data or donor subjects.</li>
            <li>Accessed data and biospecimens will not be redistributed.</li>
            <li>Access codes and user logins are specific to the identified user and are strictly non-transferable.</li>
            <li>Accessed datasets will be destroyed once they are no longer used.</li>
            <li>Biospecimens will be handled in accordance with specifications in a Material Transfer Agreement.</li>
            <li>Publications using any form of data accessed through the RDC-GPAP will contain an acknowledgment and a reference of the RDC-GPAP as appropriate.
            Where a publication makes use of individual-level datasets and enriched phenotypic data, authors should consider whether the intellectual contribution of the original contributors of the datasets qualifies for authorship positions in line with standard publication practice.</li>
            <li>Results of analyses of accessed data and biospecimens will be returned to the platform. Published work will also be sent to RD-Connect.</li>
            <li>In case of misconduct access to the platform will be withdrawn.</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <hr>
    <p>Signed on behalf of the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> on <span class="text-success">{% now "jS F Y" %}</span> by <span class="text-success">{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</span>:</p>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p>…………………………………………………</p>
    <p>Signature</p>
    <hr>
    <sup id="fn1">1. This adherence agreement is based on the Personal Data Directive, Directive95/46/EC, implying that all personal data shall be handled in accordance with Secrecy law.<a href="#ref1" title="Jump back to footnote 1 in the text.">↩</a></sup>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="printDiv('printable')" value="Print" />
    <!-- <button id="printButton" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg">Print</button> -->
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<script>
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should overwrite the `get_success_url` method of your `UserView` class

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('adherence_agreement', kwargs={'id': self.object.id})
```

[Classy Class Based Views](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_success_url) is a useful website for exploring the overridable methods of the generic class based views in Django